# Fortune while returning C arrays?

Tags: c, arrays, function

I'm newbie with C and stunned with some magic while using following C functions. **This code works for me, and prints all the data.**

```
typedef struct string_t {
    char *data;
    size_t len;
} string_t;


string_t *generate_test_data(size_t size) {
    string_t test_data[size];
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        string_t string;
        string.data = "test";
        string.len = 4;
        test_data[i] = string;
    }
    return test_data;
}

int main() {
    size_t test_data_size = 10;
    string_t *test_data = generate_test_data(test_data_size);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < test_data_size; ++i) {
        printf("%zu: %s\n", test_data[i].len, test_data[i].data);
    }
}
```

Why function generate_test_data works only when "test_data_size = 10", but when "test_data_size = 20" process finished with exit code 11? HOW does it possible?

Comment: You are returning stuff that is on the stack. I gets invalid when the function ends. It is overwritten/invalid from that point (`generate_test_data_v1`)

Comment: The `data` field is never allocated. It is assigned a pointer with stuff that is overwritten each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code will never work perfectly, it just happens to be working.  In C, you have to manage the memory yourself.  If you make a mistake, the program might continue to work... or something might scribble all over the memory you thought was yours.  This often manifests itself as weird errors like you're having: it works when the length is X, but fails when the length is Y.

If you turn on `-Wall`, or if you're using clang even better `-Weverything`, you'll get a warning like this.

```
test.c:18:12: warning: address of stack memory associated with local variable 'test_data' returned
      [-Wreturn-stack-address]
    return test_data;
           ^~~~~~~~~
```

The two important kinds of memory in C are: stack and heap.  Very basically, stack memory is only good for the duration of the function.  Anything declared on the stack will be freed automatically when the function returns, sort of like local variables in other languages.  The rule of thumb is if you don't explicitly allocate it, it's on the stack.  `string_t test_data[size];` is stack memory.

Heap memory you allocate and free yourself, usually using `malloc` or `calloc` or `realloc` or some other function doing this for you like `strdup`.  Once allocated, heap memory stays around until it's explicitly deallocated.

Rule of thumb: heap memory can be returned from a function, stack memory cannot... well, you *can* but that memory slot might then be used by something else.  That's what's happening to you.

So you need to allocate memory, not just once, but a bunch of times.

1. Allocate memory for the array of pointers to `string_t` structs.
2. Allocate memory for each `string_t` struct in the array.
3. Allocate memory for each `char` string (really an array) in each struct.

And then you have to free all that.  Sound like a lot of work?  It is!  Welcome to C.  Sorry.  You probably want to write functions to allocate and free `string_t`.

```
static string_t *string_t_new(size_t size) {
    string_t *string = malloc(sizeof(string_t));
    string->len = 0;

    return string;
}

static void string_t_destroy(string_t *self) {
    free(self);
}
```

Now your test data function looks like this.

```
static string_t **generate_test_data_v3(size_t size) {
    /* Allocate memory for the array of pointers */
    string_t **test_data = calloc(size, sizeof(string_t*));

    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        /* Allocate for the string */
        string_t *string = string_t_new(5);

        string->data = "test";
        string->len = 4;
        test_data[i] = string;
    }

    /* Return a pointer to the array, which is also a pointer */
    return test_data;
}

int main() {
    size_t test_data_size = 20;

    string_t **test_data = generate_test_data_v3(test_data_size);

    for(size_t i = 0; i < test_data_size; ++i) {
        printf("%zu: %s\n", test_data[i]->len, test_data[i]->data);
    }

    /* Free each string_t in the array */
    for(size_t i = 0; i < test_data_size; i++) {
        string_t_destroy(test_data[i]);
    }

    /* Free the array */
    free(test_data);
}
```

Instead of using pointers you *could* instead copy all the memory you use, which is sort of what you were previously doing.  That's easier for the programmer, but inefficient for the computer.  And if you're coding in C, it's all about being efficient for the computer.

Answer (score 2):

Because the space for `test_data` in v1 gets created in the function, and that space gets reclaimed when the function returns (and can thus be used for other things); in v2, the space is set aside outside of the function, so doesn't get reclaimed.

Comment: I'm also interested why generate_test_data_v1 works with "test_data_size = 10"

Comment: Or you might be in luck

Answer (score 1):

> Why function generate_test_data_v1 works only when "test_data_size = 10", but when "test_data_size = 20" process finished with exit code 11?

I see no reason why function `generate_test_data_v1()` should ever fail, but you cannot use its return value.  It returns a pointer to an automatic variable belonging to the function's scope, and automatic variables cease to exist when the function to which they belong returns.  Your program produces undefined behavior when it dereferences that pointer.  I can believe that it appears to work as you intended for some sizes, but even in those cases the program is wrong.

Moreover, your program is very unlikely to be producing an exit code of 11, but it may well be terminating abruptly with a segmentation fault, which is signal 11.

> And why generate_test_data_v2 works perfectly?

Function `generate_test_data_v2()` populates elements of an existing array belonging to function `main()`.  That array is in scope for substantially the entire life of the program.